# C# - TimeSpan doesn't work with seconds for more than one day

Tags: c#, timespan

I think the title of this question isn't good, but I couldn't find a better one.

What I'm trying to do is to give users the ability to set a count-down timer. ( Look at picture No.1 ):
[image]

The application takes the user input and checks which time unit did the user select, then converts it into seconds and assign the value to an **int** variable.

```
private int seconds = -1;

private void enable_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int amount = Convert.ToInt32(time_numericUpDown.Value);
    string unit = tUnits_comboBox.Text;

    // Check what time is chosen then convert it to seconds
    if (unit == "Seconds")
        seconds = amount;
    else if (unit == "Minutes")
        seconds = amount * 60;
    else if (unit == "Hours")
        seconds = amount * 3600;
    else if (unit == "Days")
        seconds = amount * 86400;

    // Clock it!
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

---

Then, the timer should show the time in a human-readable format, I use this code for that:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Verify if the time didn't pass
    if (seconds == 0)
    {
        // If the time is over, do the specified action
        timer.Enabled = false;
        operation(); // << This is the function that does the Action!
    }
    else
    {
        // Continue counting
        seconds -= 1;

        TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);

        string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                        timeSpan.Hours,
                        timeSpan.Minutes,
                        timeSpan.Seconds);

        status_label.Text = "Restarting in " + answer;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly when the value of the "seconds" variable represents one day or less, but when it's more than 24 hours it just shows 24 hours in the status. What am I doing wrong?

( The problem ):

[image]

Comment: nothing, this is just how timespan is implemented....

Comment: @AlaaJoseph were you expecting `47:59:56`?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName So, how can I make it work? Do I have to use math instead of `TimeSpan`?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) if that is your maximum value you want to display.  If you look at the TimeSpan it will also have a value in the Days property.

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(48, 0, 0);
MessageBox.Show(ts.Days.ToString() + " - " + ts.Hours.ToString());   // 2 - 0
MessageBox.Show(ts.TotalHours.ToString());                           // 48
```

Note that TotalHours is a double that represents fractional hours:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(47, 59, 0);
MessageBox.Show(ts.Days.ToString() + " - " + ts.Hours.ToString());   // 1 - 23
MessageBox.Show(ts.TotalHours.ToString());                           // 47.98333
```

So to get the value you want to display, you should round it down:

```
 TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(47, 59, 0);
 MessageBox.Show(Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours).ToString());              // 47
```

Answer (score 3):

All of the properties that don't start with `Total` contain only the remainder that didn't fit into the next higher property.

In other words: The `Days` property will contain the value `1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [list of properties in `TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties.aspx), this might make more sense. The [`Hours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.hours.aspx) property only shows the "hours" portion, just like you see `56` for the "seconds" portion instead of `172,796` (which is 2 days minus 4 seconds). There's also a `Days` portion. You want to use [`TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx) (which is a `double` showing the whole amount in hours; something like `47.99995` in your example) and [`Math.Floor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx):

```
    string answer = string.Format("{0:00}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                    Math.Floor(timeSpan.TotalHours),
                    timeSpan.Minutes,
                    timeSpan.Seconds);
```

This will result, in your example, in `47:59:56`.

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
```

when the hour of timespan become more than 24 hours then that will be treated as a day. So you will have to calculate that way.

Example :

if total seconds : 93600 that means 26 hours and for timespan it will be 1 day and 2 hours.

Hope you understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try TotalHours instead of Hours.

```
string answer = string.Format("{0:00}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s",
                    timeSpan.TotalHours,
                    timeSpan.Minutes,
                    timeSpan.Seconds);
```

Comment: `D2` isn't valid for a `double`. This results in "FormatException: Format specifier was invalid."

Answer (score 1):

`Hours` gets the hours component of the time interval represented by the current TimeSpan structure. (from msdn)

There are also 'Days' component which you simply don't show.